# Browsermob Proxy Maven dependency convergence errors

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm new to maven and I'm getting some dependency convergence errors that don't make sense to me. The errors I'm getting are

```
[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final paths to dependency are:
+-example:framework:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1
    +-net.lightbody.bmp:littleproxy:1.1.0-beta-bmp-5
      +-io.netty:netty-all:4.0.23.Final
and
+-example:framework:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1
    +-io.netty:netty-all:4.0.27.Final

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for com.google.guava:guava:18.0 paths to dependency are:
+-example:framework:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1
    +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.0-beta-1
      +-com.google.guava:guava:18.0
and
+-example:framework:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1
    +-net.lightbody.bmp:littleproxy:1.1.0-beta-bmp-5
      +-com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0 paths to dependency are:
+-example:framework:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1
    +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.0-beta-1
      +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4
        +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
and
+-example:framework:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1
    +-net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.0-beta-1
      +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.4
```

They are confusing to me because it looks to me like they all sprout from the same dependency, does that mean the net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core-littleproxy:2.1.0-beta-1 is broken?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-core-littleproxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-beta-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still bothered by the conflicts within the same package, but I managed to fix it by excluding the conflicting dependencies from the bmp dependency and then explicitly adding the newer version #'s as dependencies in my project.